# Where can I download Selenium-2.47 Jar files?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, java

> Where can I download Selenium-2.47 or Selenium-2.47 JavaDoc Jar file?

Comment: What did you try to find what you need?

Comment: I have a tool I use for these kinds of questions: http://bfy.tw/15me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Selenium download page contains both a link to Selenium and the JavaDoc: http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

The download page also links to the Maven locations: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-server/2.47.1/

Comment: Yes but it does the first link file :(

Comment: The link to the Maven repo's do :) Its the third link on the download page..

Answer (score -2):

You can download directly from Selenium side
http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

select Version which would you like to want download.

Java    2.47.1  2015-07-29  Download    Change log      Javadoc

Comment: Mentioning 'Download Change log Javadoc' doesn't add any value to the answer. Only link was fine.